# Why is it hard to bring back a once "broken" neural network to usable results ? - Classification MNIST SGD

Tags: neural-networks, stochastic-gradient-descent

I'm currently working through Michael Nielsens book "[Neural Networks and Deep  Learning](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/)" .

If I use his [code](https://github.com/mnielsen/neural-networks-and-deep-learning/blob/master/src/network.py)/hyperparameters the network get's quite a good classification score. Even after the first epoch !

**Output - Randomly initialized neural net**

```py
# 30 epochs, batch size = 10, learning rate = 3.0
net = network.Network([784, 20, 10])
net.SGD(training_data, 30, 10, 3.0, test_data=test_data)
```

```
Epoch 0: 8992 / 10000
Epoch 1: 9181 / 10000
Epoch 2: 9236 / 10000
Epoch 3: 9323 / 10000
Epoch 4: 9284 / 10000
```

I played around a bit with too high learning rates and as expected the classification results got worse.

**Breaking a net with a high learning rate:**

```py
broken_net = network.Network([784, 20, 10])
# 30 epochs, batch size = 5000, learning rate = 300.0
broken_net.SGD(training_data, 30, 5000, 300.0, test_data=test_data)
```

```
Epoch 0: 3876 / 10000
Epoch 1: 3289 / 10000
Epoch 2: 3288 / 10000
Epoch 3: 3365 / 10000
```

**Trying to bring it back to live:**

Please note i use all the **same hyperparameters** as for the **working example** above.

```py
# 30 epochs, batch size = 10, learning rate = 3.0
broken_net.SGD(training_data, 30, 10, 3.0, test_data=test_data)
```

```
Epoch 1: 3905 / 10000
Epoch 2: 3878 / 10000
Epoch 3: 3875 / 10000
Epoch 4: 3883 / 10000
Epoch 5: 3891 / 10000
Epoch 6: 3901 / 10000
Epoch 7: 3929 / 10000
Epoch 8: 3907 / 10000
Epoch 9: 3924 / 10000
..
..
Epoch 26: 4004 / 10000
Epoch 27: 3988 / 10000
Epoch 28: 3975 / 10000
Epoch 29: 3966 / 10000
```

### Question

How can it be that a **randomly initialized** Neural Network gets **accurate** already after **1 epoch** of training , **but** the broken one **doesn't even get close** to the performance of the randomly initialized net **even after 30 epochs** ?

What I would actually expect is that it's easier to get the "broken net"  back to higher scores. Since the expectation value for digit classification would be 10% accuracy (for a random net). And the broken net had a accuracy of 33%.

I mean it could be that it trapped the gradient descent in a minimum but this phenomenon seems quite reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite hard to say without knowing more details. It's likely that by updating with such a large learning rate, you've sent the weights off to some region where they are not amenable to further optimization.

If you're familiar with how important correct weight initialization is for training neural networks (indeed, with very careful initialization, it's possible to train [10000 layer networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.05393.pdf)!) -- then it shouldn't come as a surprise that by violently disturbing the weights, you may have messed up the initialization so much that it's not able to recover.

Comment: Hi thx for your answer, what more details should i provide ? 

Actually i was not familiar with how important the initilalization was, so thx for sharing this paper.

Comment: "you may have messed up the initialization so much that it's not able to recover." 

What i am interested in is **why** it's not able to recover. Is it because of a local minimum it can't escape ? Though i thought with SGD this shouldn't be that big of a problem.